# Regardless of composition, can I say monadic if there is only a way to change m(m a) to m a

Tags: haskell, monads

Monad has the following components.

1. **a** and **m a** which converted from **a** by a Functor
2. **a -> m b** arrow and a way to change **m m** to **m**
3. composition of arrows

If there is a structure that has 1,2 regardless of composition, can I say it's Monadic?

Sure, If a structure has 1 and 2, It can be composed. but It doesn't have to be concerned or not?

edited:

I thought that associativity, Identity are about composition. If a structure has all exactly, It's just a Monad. My Question is about "Monadic". the most important factor of Monad is mu(join), so if a structure has only mu, Could it be a Monadic thing roughly ?

or
Monadic is just an adjective for Monad.
"Monadic" thing means that It's a factor of a Monad.
**Monadic structure** of a Monad
**Monadic type** m a of a Monad,
**Monadic arrow** a -> m b of a Monad,
**Monadic compostion** >=> of a Monad
...

Comment: The monad laws are a pretty important part.

Comment: What do you mean by "composition" in this context? If you mean kleisli arrows, I believe they follow naturally if you have a lawful monad

Comment: Does the [monadic functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+functor) definition answer your question? Probably together with the [monadicity theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadicity+theorem).

Comment: Neither `join` nor `return` is more important than the other: you need both. (Regarding #2, if you have `join`, you can define `>>=`, and vice versa.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like two questions: a question about terminology, and a question about whether the monad laws relate to "composition" only.

For the terminology question...

As pointed out by @cstml in a comment, there's a formal definition of a "monadic functor" in category theory, but I don't think Haskell programmers typically use "monadic" in this formal sense, and it doesn't look like you're asking about that.

When I use the term "monadic", I typically use it in the sense of "things pertaining to a monad".  So a monadic action is an expression of the form `m a` for a `Monad m` and when I engage in monadic programming, I'm using monads.

I don't typically use it in the sense of "monad-like", but I could see maybe saying something like "arrows have some monadic behavior, but they aren't necessarily monads".  On the other hand, if you say "type `X` is monadic" without qualification, that sounds like just an unusual way of saying "type `X` is a monad".

For the monad laws question...

Even though the monad laws for Haskell are usually expressed in terms of `return` and `>>=`, an alternative set of laws that only involve `return`, `fmap`, and `join` can be formulated.  That is, the `join` operator all by itself satisfies identity and associativity laws that are more or less equivalent to the laws satisfied by `>>=`.

Specifically, any monad obeys the obvious laws:

```
fmap f . return = return . f
join . fmap return = id
join . return = id
```

If you have an object that supports operations:

```
return :: a -> m a       -- convert from `a` by functor
join :: m (m a) -> m a   -- change `m m` to `m`
```

but doesn't satisfy any of these laws, then it doesn't seem very "monadic".

If it *does* satisfy the above laws, then the composition defined by:

```
x >>= f = join (fmap f x)
```

will automatically satisfy the usual Haskell left and right identity laws:

```
return a >>= k = k a
m >>= return = m
```

so these laws aren't "just about composition".

The only usual Haskell law not implied by the above is associativity.  Like the others, it can be expressed in terms of `join` and `fmap` instead of `>>=` and it takes the form:

```
join . fmap h . join . fmap k = join . fmap (join . fmap h . k)
```

Basically, the question of associativity can either be expressed as the associativity of the composition of monad arrows *or* as the associativity of the `join` operation acting on the type `m m m a` -- in other words, does it matter if you join the outer layer first or the inner layer first?

Comment: I think it might be okay to say the monad laws are just about composition. If you write them as `return >=> f = f`, `f >=> return = f`, and `f >=> (g >=> h) = (f >=> g) >=> h`, there's a clear parallel to the composition laws, namely `id . f = f`, `f . id = id`, and `f . (g . h) = f . (g . h)`.

Comment: Well, I think the OP is thinking that composition of the monadic arrows `a -> m b` in **Hask** can somehow be separated from composition of the join operation (as a monoid in the category of endofunctors, ha ha).  My point is merely that associativity is just as much a property of `join` as of `>=>` or `>>=`.